# Returning a dictionary value in C# without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to use the value of a dictionary without assigning it to a variable:

```
Dictionary<int, string> LayoutByID = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    { 0, "foo"},
    { 1, "bar"}
    // ...
};
```

I can for e.g. print the values if I create a variable:

```
string b;
LayoutByID.TryGetValue(1,out b);
print("Trying Dictionary to retrieve value for 1: " + b);
```

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way, something like:

```
print("Trying Dictionary to retrieve value for 1: " + LayoutByID.TryGetValue(1 [???]));
```

I understand I could write a function with a switch in it that would work similarly, but using Dictionaries might be cheaper as I have a longer list.
Thanks for advice!

Comment: What would you want to happen if the key doesn't exist? Besides, assigning to a variable doesn't cost anything. A reference to the value will be generated in either way.

Comment: In the current context I can easily ensure that the key exists, as I have control on both sides. Nevertheless very handy to know how to handle exceptions when it is not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the `Dictionary` with the key like `var x = LayoutByID[0];` But you will get an exception, if the `Dictionary`does not contain an entry with that key.

In order to avoid an exception being throw, you can first check if the key exists using `LayoutByID.ContainsKey()` - and then write your logic for those cases:

```
if (LayoutByID.ContainsKey(0)) // Check if the key exists (replace 0 with whatever)
{
    var x = LayoutByID[0]; // Access the value and do whatever with it
    // ...
}
else
{
    // Key doesn't exist:
    // Do something else
}
```

or with C# 6.0 you could also print like this

```
var key = -1;
var myString = string.Empty;
LayoutByID.TryGetValue(key, out myString);
Console.WriteLine($"Trying Dictionary to retrieve value for {key}: {myString ?? "Error: Invalid ID"}");
```

Comment: Tx! I knew there must be a simple way, but no googling wanted to give me this answer...

Comment: To add to this, you could also do a check to see if it contains the `Key` you are after: `if (LayoutById.ContainsKey(0)) { ... // do stuff }` - to save an exception being thrown

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own extension method.

```
[Extension]
public static string GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
                                                     TKey key, 
                                                     TValue defaultValue)
{
    if(this.ContainKey(key) == true) return this[i];
    return defaultValue;       
}
```

Then use it

```
Console.WriteLine("Print value for key 1: " + LayoutByID.GetValueOrDefault(1, ""));)
```

With extension method you will get more clearer and readable code and can use same logic in other places

Comment: LayoutByID.SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(1)).Value is there already - it will give you the value or null if key is not there.

Answer (score 1):

```
int selectingvalue = 1;
print(LayoutByID.ContainsKey(selectingvalue) ? LayoutByID.First(x => x.Key == selectingvalue).Value : "");
```

Comment: Could you not just use `print(LayoutById.First(x => x.Key == selectingvalue).Select(x => x.Value)` ?

Comment: My bad (that way is for `IEnumerable`s) - you could use `LayoutByID.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == selectingValue).Value;`

Comment: yeah i figured it out like that

Comment: but this is still not the best solution because it gives an error if the key is not in the dictionary

Comment: That's why you need to use `FirstOrDefault` ;)

Comment: thank you for correcting me though.. learning linq and still a but difficult for me

Comment: No problem @Neil - but now you've changed your answer altogether (don't get me wrong it still works). FYI `First()` can throw an exception if the predicate (in this case, key) doesn't exist; `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't throw an exception if the predicate/key doesn't exists, but instead returns the default value :)

Comment: @GeoffJames yeah thank you. thats why i added the containskey in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you seem to have with not wanting to assign to a variable seems to be that you want to retrieve a Dictionary value in short and concise code without the extra 'noise' of having to check the value exists and prevent an "unhandled null exception".

In this case I would recommend using a [null-coalescing operator.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173224.aspx) It works like this:

```
x ?? y
```

If x is null, y will be used. If x is not null, x will be used.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Trying Dictionary to retrieve value for 1: {LayoutByID[0] ?? "value not found"}")
```

This way you do not have to do any checks first, and in case of null, you will be defaulted to "value not found".

That said, its probably not the best thing to put a bit of logic inside the Console.WriteLine(). I personally would prefer to do this (although you have said you don't want to assign to a variable first):

```
var x = LayoutByID[0] ?? "value not found"
Console.WriteLine($"Trying Dictionary to retrieve value for 1: {x}")
```

Comment: But won't `Dictionary` throw an exception if the key doesn't exist? I know the null coalescent operator sets a different value if the key exists and is `null` (which is a great idea), but if the key isn't there, shouldn't you consider an exception being thrown? :)

Comment: Yes, in that case you should check first if the key exists with `LayoutByID.ContainsKey(0)` or any of the other options discussed in the top answer. If you are CERTAIN that the key exists in the dictionary, then a more terse solution would be to use the null-coalescing operator. Choosing the right tool for the job is probably dependent on more factors outside of the question.